# How can I select a data in python DataFrame (table) that depends on three column(variable)?

Tags: python, dataframe

At first from a table (Data frame) I find the ID, Frame Type and Frame material (Aluminum and wood). Then I want to come to this data frame and write a function to find the corresponding value.

For example, from the first data frame I understand that: `ID = 1c` , `Frame_type = fixed` and `Frame material = aluminum`.

but I don't know how to write a function to find this value which depends on three variables.

[image]

Comment: Can you write a function that depends on one variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find rows by three values, you can use this construction

```
df = df[((df.ID == x1) & (df.Frame_type == x2) & (df.Aluminum == x3))]
```

If this isn't a solution, can you clarify the question?